# Data structure needed

Tags: data-structures

After doing some thought I came to the conclusion that I require a data structure that supports:

- Insert
- Remove
- Find
- Delete minimum

of course I want to implement this in the best complexity I can.

My thoughts are that a Self-balancing binary search tree will do A-D in O(log(n)) (worst case).
Maybe this can be improved somehow so A-C will be in O(log(n)) and D (that I think will be more frequent) will run in O(1).

I do a worst case analysis, but if you can think of something that will run 'fast' but it's Amortized analysis or on average than it's no problem.
any improvement to what I have in mind is welcomed!

(note: I believe that A and D will be much more frequent that B and C)

Comment: Are you asking a theoretical question or for a real implementation in a programming language?

Comment: @Foo Bah - a real implementation in a programming language (Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be some sort of sorted, balanced tree. It is not likely that any tree will be significantly better suited for the minimum deletion, as it will still require re-balancing anyway. All of the operations you ask for will be O(log(n)). Red-black trees are readily available in C++ and Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re describing is a [**priority queue**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), augmented by a “find” operation.

It is usually implemented in terms of a [**min-heap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). All operations you listed, except “find”, run in O(log *n*), and it is notably the *most efficient* overall data structure for this job. It is important to note that this is a special case of a binary tree that can be implemented much more efficiently than a general binary search tree, both in terms of memory consumption and performance (same asymptotic performance but much better constant factors).

Unfortunately, “find” still takes O(*n*).

It is implemented in Java in the [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class.